# issue with multiple queries in solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

We are facing a strange issue with the solr. When we query with particular field the query is not returning any values.
Query 1: I am specifying an isbn number and extracting all the values available in publisher filed. Which is working as expected.

Query2 : We have specified and extra condition for Publisher  this time but the query is returning 0 records , which should have returned 2

[Screenshot with both the queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgjW3.jpg)

Comment: Please share with us your shema.xml

Comment: In particular - what's the definition of the fieldType used for `Publisher`? Initial guess is that there are different analyzers or filters present for `index` and `query`.

Comment: thanks for the help. We were able to find the issue . There was some data issue.

Publisher:%22University%20of%C2%A0Hawaii%C2%A0Press%22
We found that there are some invalid characters (%C2%A0) instead of space

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find the issue . There was some data issue. 
Publisher:%22University%20of%C2%A0Hawaii%C2%A0Press%22

We found that there are some invalid characters (%C2%A0) instead of space